# Get Max of AVG in Symfony 2.4 Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4

I need to get MAX of list of AVG  in symfony doctrine

My doctrine query to get average is as follows :

```
SELECT p,AVG(p.pathTime) as avgtime 
FROM ShopperAnalyticsEntityBundle:Path p 
 JOIN p.shopper sh JOIN p.floor f 
 JOIN f.store s 
WHERE p.floor=".$floorId." ".$filter." 
GROUP BY p.xPath, p.yPath
```

To get the max of the list of averages I modified it to (after referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3962487/1319642)):

```
SELECT MAX(avgtime) as maxtime 
FROM (SELECT p,AVG(p.pathTime) as avgtime 
      FROM ShopperAnalyticsEntityBundle:Path p 
       JOIN p.shopper sh 
       JOIN p.floor f 
       JOIN f.store s 
      WHERE p.floor=".$floorId." ".$filter." 
      GROUP BY p.xPath, p.yPath)
```

I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 38 near '(SELECT p,AVG(p.pathTime)': Error: Class '(' is not defined
```

So I switched to native SQL to get the same result:

```
$maxSQL   = "SELECT MAX(t.avgtime) as maxtime FROM ( SELECT AVG(p.path_time) as avgtime FROM  path p JOIN shopper sh JOIN floor f JOIN store s WHERE p.floor_id=".$floorId." ".$filter." GROUP BY p.x_path, p.y_path ) t ";

$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare($maxSQL);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

I get the result but SQL takes 23.4457 seconds to run

Can anyone suggest an easy way to solve this in Doctrine.

Comment: What kind of database engine do you use ? MySQL ? You will need to create your own doctrine extension to match to the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dotrine this way :

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('MAX(avgtime) as maxtime ')
  ->from('(SELECT p,AVG(p.pathTime) as avgtime 
           FROM ShopperAnalyticsEntityBundle:Path p 
           JOIN p.shopper sh 
           JOIN p.floor f 
           JOIN f.store s 
           WHERE p.floor=".$floorId." ".$filter." 
           GROUP BY p.xPath, p.yPath)
        ')
  ->execute();
```

How did you yours ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Healkiss I use Symfony 2.4 I wasn't able to locate the class Doctrine_Query

Comment: Probably with $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager()->createQuery(...) in a controller.